# Animating a section of a path using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to animate a section of a path using canvas. Basically I have a straight line that runs through three links. When you hover over a link the section of the path behind the link should animate into a sine wave.

I have no problem animating the whole path into the shape of a sine wave but when it comes to animating a section of a path, I'm at a loss :(

I've attached a reference image below to give an idea of what it is I'm trying to achieve.

[image: reference image]

Below is jsfiddle of the code I'm currently using to animate the path. I'm a canvas noob so forgive me if it awful...

https://jsfiddle.net/9mu8xo0L/

and here is the code:

```
class App {

      constructor() {

        this.drawLine();

      }

      drawLine() {

        this.canvas = document.getElementById('sine-wave');
        this.canvas.width = 1000;

        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.cpY = 0;
        this.movement = 1;
        this.fps = 60;

        this.ctx.moveTo(0, 180);
        this.ctx.lineTo(1000, 180);
        this.ctx.stroke();

        this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', this.draw.bind(this));

      }

      draw() {

        setTimeout(() => {

          if (this.cpY >= 6) return;

          requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));

          // animate the control point
          this.cpY += this.movement;

          const increase = (90 / 180) * (Math.PI / 2);
          let counter = 0;
          let x = 0;
          let y = 180;

          this.ctx.beginPath();

          this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

          for(let i = 0; i <= this.canvas.width; i += 6) {

            this.ctx.moveTo(x,y);

            x = i;
            y =  180 - Math.sin(counter) * this.cpY;

            counter += increase;

            this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            this.ctx.stroke();

          }

        }, 1000 / this.fps);

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split the drawing of the line in three parts, drawing 1/3 as straight line, animate the mid section and add the last 1/3.

I'll demonstrate the first 1/3 + animation and leave the last 1/3 as an exercise (also moved the `stroke()` outside the loop so it doesn't overdraw per segment) - there is room for refactoring and optimizations here but I have not addressed that in this example -

```
  let x = this.canvas.width / 3;   // start of part 2 (animation)
  let y = 180;

  this.ctx.beginPath();

  this.ctx.clearRect(0, x, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

  // draw first 1/3
  this.ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);

  // continue with part 2
  for(let i = x; i <= this.canvas.width; i += 6) {
    x = i;
    y = 180 - Math.sin(counter) * this.cpY;

    counter += increase;

    // add to 2. segment
    this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  // stroke line
  this.ctx.stroke();
```

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9mu8xo0L/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @K3N. This is what I was looking for, the only issue is that the sections aren't seamless. Have a look at this updated fiddle to see what I mean. This was what I was really not sure about... https://jsfiddle.net/9mu8xo0L/3/

Comment: @Ashmore11 you could extend the line to 2/3 and force y, then draw the last segment at same y. Updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9mu8xo0L/4/